# Parsing csv with c

Tags: c

I have the following to parse a csv file, and it works fine until i changed

```
(getfield(tmp, 12));
```

to

```
(getfield(tmp, ver));
```

Is the problem in function declaration   ?

here is the code :

```
const char* getfield(char* line, int num)
{
    const char* tok;
    for (tok = strtok(line, ";");
            tok && *tok;
            tok = strtok(NULL, ";\n"))
    {
        if (!--num)
            return tok;
    }
    return NULL;
}
int main() {
    double frame_index[40][300];
    int horz;
    FILE* fp = fopen("output.txt", "r");
    char line[1024];

        for (int ver; ver<20;ver++) {
            while (fgets(line, 1024, fp))  {
                char* tmp = strdup(line);
                frame_index[ver][horz] = atof(getfield(tmp, ver));  
                // works if "ver" was explicitly defined
                printf("AA %f\n", frame_index[ver][horz]);
                free(tmp);
                horz++;     
        }   
         rewind(fp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `getfield()` may return `NULL`.  Need to test for that before calling `atof()`.

Answer (score 2):

You never initialize the variable `ver`. For example you might want to change

```
for (int ver; ver<20;ver++)
```

to

```
for (int ver=0; ver<20;ver++)
```

**Update** The same with `horz`..

Comment: still getting a segfault :(

Comment: shouldn't be initialization  automatically  ?

Comment: For automatic (local) variables? No.

Comment: tried initializing the variables to zero, no avail thou.

Comment: Then you have additional problems. For example you never check your file has no more than 300 lines. Also you don't check each line is correct format. You should add some error-handling. And I would avoid composite constructs negation/predecrement and the token manipulation inside the `for` statement.

Comment: I am sure there are libraries out there. Never used on though.. `libcsv` is the first google result.