# Confusion about const char * declarations in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-management

I know this may seem like a stupid question, but I am really having trouble understanding some particular examples of C code that involve a declaration of type `const char *`.

The example that got me thinking about it is in the answer at [Parsing csv with c](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36037200/16663827). In particular, the function defined as:

```
const char* getfield(char* line, int num)
{
    const char* tok;
    for (tok = strtok(line, ";");
            tok && *tok;
            tok = strtok(NULL, ";\n"))
    {
        if (!--num)
            return tok;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

My understanding of `const char *` declarations is that it defines a mutable pointer to an immutable array of characters. This array is assigned in the data section at compile time. However in this case (and many other code examples), the `const char *` declaration is not for a string literal. How can this memory be assigned for this at compile time if the actual value of the string is not known until the function executes?

Comment: There is an example in the standard "const float *" is not a qualified type — its type is "pointer to const-qualified float" and is a pointer to a qualified type (6.2.5, 32).  You promise that you will not modify what tok points to, and if you do, it undefined behavior.

Comment: @AllanWind I think a standard would be super helpful. Is this the ANSI C standard, or K&R, or something else?

Comment: The last working draft of ISO/IEC9899:2017 is freely available.

Comment: `const char T*` declares a pointer to an object (which might be the first object in an array of such objects) *which you promise you won't try to modify*. The compiler will probably help you keep that promise by producing warning or error messages if it detects that you are trying to modify an object through that pointer, but it can't actually know in all cases. However, it is allowed to optimise, assuming that you will play by the rules. If you read a value from that pointer twice, the compiler might eliminate the second read and assume that the first value is still valid.

Comment: Anyway, if you will not using a pointer to modify a value, it makes sense to declare it as a pointer to `const`. The compiler is likely to produce useful error messages (since modifying a value you didn't plan to modify is almost certainly an error). It might even warn you about passing the pointer as an argument to a function which might try to modify the value pointed to. So it can help. But it doesn't guarantee that the memory being pointed at is read-only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this

```
const char* tok;
```

creates a pointer on the stack. It has an undefined value, it points nowhere

this

```
for (tok = strtok(line, ";");
```

then makes it point to somewhere in `line` (depends on contents)

your comments

> My understanding of const char * declarations is that it defines a mutable pointer to an immutable array of characters. This array is assigned in the data section at compile time.

First sentence, almost, it creates a pointer that might point to an immutable array of chars. Like this

```
  const char * msg = "hello world";
```

But is can also point nowhere

```
 const char * msg = NULL;
```

Or to a mutable array of characters

```
 char msg[] = "HelloWorld"; // mutable
 const char *msgconst = msg;
```

the second sentence

> This array is assigned in the data section at compile time

Yes, if this is a literal. Ie like this example again

```
  const char*msg = "Hello World";
```

but the `msgconst` assignment is not like that, the characters are on the stack

Hope this helps

EDIT

The pointer points where it is told to do, making it const or not has zero effect on where the data is. The data is where it is.(!). You need to think about where the data is created, nothing to do with the pointer, the pointer can point at a literal, stack data, static data (mutable in data segment), heap.

Why use const

- if the string is immutable then the pointer must be const. C allows you to assign a literal to a non const pointer for historical reasons, c++ does not
- You want to make it clear that this string should not be changed. In your code case you really should not mess with the string strtok is processing. Although it returns char* , this is good practice
- functions like strlen that do not change the string passed to them declare their arguments as const char*, its part of their contract: we dont change the string

But having the word `const` does not change anything about storage, and does not save any space anywhere

Comment: This is very helpful. So the array that it points to is not always assigned to the data section, but only when it is a string literal. I guess the only other question I have is what is the benefit of using "const char *" instead of just "char *" here? I assumed the benefit is usually that it saves precious space on the stack, but in this case the characters will get put there anyway. What benefit does "const" give?

Comment: @Luke see edits

Comment: Thanks for the reply, although I am slightly more confused now. As you mentioned in your edits, the const char * pointer can point to a *mutable* array. So now I am even more curious as to what the benefit of it is as opposed to just declaring char * without the "const".

Sorry if these are trivial questions, as you can tell I am a complete beginner.

Comment: If a function argument is const-qualified then caller can assume that the value is not changed, otherwise caller would have copy before passing it in the value.

Comment: @AllanWind thank you, that makes a lot of sense. And thanks for the standard, I will go take a look.

Comment: @Luke just beacuse my string is mutable doesnt mean I want it changed. Declaring it const makes the intent clear an dprevents accidental changes by me, future maintainers or functions I call